# multiple jqGrid usercontrols in same page

Tags: c#, jqgrid

I tried to populate id depend on usercontrols id but I endup with no error and not working.
I dont copy all code its extremly long, but I am pasting sample which shows what I did and `console.log("arrived")` doesn't get fired.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var <%=this.ClientID%>_grid_selector = "#<%=this.ClientID%>_grid-table";
    var <%=this.ClientID%>_pager_selector = "#<%=this.ClientID%>_grid-pager";
```

...

```
    jQuery(<%=this.ClientID%>_grid_selector).jqGrid({
        data: <%=this.ClientID%>_master,
        datatype: "local",
        height: 420,
        colNames: <%=this.ClientID%>_ColNames,
        colModel: <%=this.ClientID%>_ColModel,
        afterInsertRow: function(rowId, rowData, rowElement) {
            console.log("arrived");
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: are you working on aspx or mvc ?

Comment: I am woking on aspx/ascx

Comment: You don't posted HTML/ASPX fragment of controls which you want to reference. Isn't it more easy to specify `id` values directly in your HTML code (by adding `ClientIDMode="Static"`)? Why you need to use controls with `runat="server"` at all for jqGrid? You need just to have an empty `<table>` and an empty `<div>` both having `id` attributes. Why you need to use `runat="server"` here and reference it via `ClientID`?

Comment: Its a Generic User Control, I dont specify any id, and If I use 2 same usercontrol in same page they get same ids.